# Detect the ethernet link up event and run the script

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

Hi i would like to run the script on ethernet link up event detection.

I tried to put the script in /etc/network/if-up.d/ but it didn't work for me. So Is there any way to detect the event every time and run the script ?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: currently, i am using the Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I think there are different ways of controlling ubuntu, and this is where you are having issues - the one is through scripts like /etc/network/interfaces (which should support the if-up.d directory or adding a command "up") - the other is through Network Manager - which is generally associated with the GUI. (If you are using this method, just make sure your script is executable using chmod 755 script.sh)

It is not entirely clear that it is possible to get scripts working with Network Manager - but [it has been suggested on the Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258580/how-to-run-a-script-depending-on-internet-connection) that this may be possible by having an entry in /etc/network/interfaces with an Interface type of "Manual".  This - in theory - will Network Manager control it, but will also execute scripts in the if-up.d directory.

Comment: Hey thanx it worked when i manually down the interface by running the  sudo ifdown eth0 command. And then bring up the interface by sudo ifup eth0 command. But i want to run this script when i detached the ethernet cable at run time and when i attached the ethernet cable it will detect the link up state and run the script . So can you guide me through this problem..